# Set-MgUserLicense insufficient privileges, even though they are included

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I know I am missing something, but I can't find a solution.  I am writing a script that removes an AD user's licenses from their account.  I call `Connect-Graph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All, Organization.Read.All` at the top of the script, but the call to Set-MgUserLicense returns an insufficient privileges operation.  I read through the docs and applied the same permissions as the examples show, but it still won't work, even while using an elevated powershell prompt while logged into my AD admin account.

**Update**

Here is the script I am trying to use.

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All, Organization.Read.All
Connect-Graph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All, Organization.Read.All -NoWelcome 
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD

# Get username, prepare it's new OU
$username = Read-Host "Enter the username to disable"
$TargetOU = "OU=Disabled Accounts,OU=3_Users,DC=XXXX,DC=com"
# grab user from AD based on $username
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $username } -Properties MemberOf


# License removal
$licenses = Get-MgSubscribedSku -All
$email = $username + "@gmail.com"
Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $email -AddLicenses @() -RemoveLicenses @($licenses.SkuId)
```

And the error message

[image: Error]

Comment: I have a Connect-MgGraph statement above the Connect-Graph, which is for some other AD related cmdlets I use in the same script.  The MgGraph dependent cmdlets work without issue, it's just the Set-MgUserLicence I am struggling with.

Comment: Please show us the command you use and also the error message in Full. [edit] your question and put that in, not in a comment because that loses all formatting.

Comment: The script is on my work computer, I can't access it until Monday.  But I will post it asap.

Comment: @Theo I just posted the script.  I appreciate any help if you are still interested.

Comment: The error message is about you having no permissions.. Perhaps you should look at [example 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.authentication/connect-mggraph?view=graph-powershell-1.0#example-8-using-client-secret-credentials) on Connect-MgGraph to make sure you connect as someone that does have permissions? By the way, why do you `Connect-AzureAD` twice?

Comment: Why would the Connect-MgGraph at the top not be sufficient for this cmdlet?  I have tried using example 8, but it keeps rejecting the user name that is authorized to administer our AD.  As for the double Connect-AzureAD:  I don't know quite yet, I am basically redoing someone else's script.